# Laptop can't connect to wired network

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, wireless-router

I have a wired internet connected to my PC. If I try to connect the same wire to my laptop it does not work.

I also have Netgear Wireless 150 router. I want my Laptop to connect to WiFi through the router. How can I achieve this?

Comment: are you able to receive the wifi network in the laptop?

Comment: yes I am able to access internet through my laptops WIFI network

Comment: login to your router from laptop and check the settings.

Comment: I have checked all the router setting but not results. I had checked with the internet provider and he said that the IP address of the PC is registered with them and if wanted to add another PC/laptop then I have to pay extra. But I want to use the same connection for both PC and Laptop.Can I replicate the PC IP address to the Laptop?

Comment: yes you can do this if you have two nic card in your system. just connect to the internet through one nic card to your service provider and connect your laptop to another nic card and configure LAN provide gateway address to your second nic card the ip address you  get on another nic card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto your desktop and get the following info:

Open a cmd prompt (run "cmd"). Type "ipconfig". Find the IP4 Address, subnet mask & default gateway.

Now go to laptop and do the same and compare the two computers: The IP4 address should be within the same range, but the subnet mask and default gateway should be the same.

Open the network connections properties on the laptop and set the static ip4 properties to match the desktops.

about the wifi? Do you see the SSID? Make sure the routers wireless is on by checking the router information-> Use your desktop and open a browser to your routers web settings, the web address is

```
http://defaultgateway_from_ipconfig/
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a silly question, but is your NIC *active*? check this in Network & Sharing Center.
I once had this same issue, having inadvertently deactivated the LAN connection, but leaving WiFi active.